# convert numeric seconds to minutes in powerBI

Tags: sql, reporting, powerbi, dax

I'm trying to convert seconds to minutes using dax formula in powerBI. eg. if the seconds value is 120 the minutes value should be 2 and if the seconds value is 15 then minutes value should be 0. i'm using the formula `Minutes = MOD([load_duration_in_seconds],3600)/60` but this returns decimal values eg. 94 sec = 1.57 mins. i need this value to be rounded as 1. i tried casting the column as INT like `Minutes = INT(MOD([load_duration_in_seconds],3600)/60)` but this returns value 0 for most of the values and doesn't return correct value. What could be wrong?

Comment: isn't it as simple as: `INT([load_duration_in_seconds]/60)`

Comment: The code you provided is actually [working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHR2s.png). You may want to provide more details on your exact case for troubleshooting.

Comment: Do you want the seconds truncated to the nearest minute, or do you want them rounded to the nearest minute?  What do you expect if the value is 119 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve this by simply casting the result to an INT. This will always remove the decimal part, which is what you are after.

Examples:

```
INT(MOD(94,3600)/60) //Result: 1
INT(MOD(15,3600)/60) //Result: 0
INT(MOD(1555,3600)/60) //Result: 25
```

DAX does also offer a ROUNDDOWN() function that takes two parameters: number, num_digits. You could also use this function to solve your case, but casting it to an INT is a more simple solution.